# How to return a Json Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm trying to implement a methodA in my C# restserviceA which returns a Json message to the client.

The method simply makes another restservice call to an internally hosted service, Say ResterviceB like below

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "GET";
resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
            loResponseStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            string strResponse = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            return resp;
```

This method would get a response in json format from RestServiceB. How could I return the same json string to the client in json format itself.

I tried putting the webmethod attributes as below to my methodA but the response I get from MethodA from RestServiceA is always in string format.

SVC interface:

```
[OperationContract ]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "getresults", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
String GetResults();
```

SVC code

```
public String GetResults()
{
   string str=//Call RestServiceB which returns response as below.
   "query":"myquery", "results": [ {"name":"result1", "type":"suggest"}, {"name":"result2", "type":"type2"}]" 
    return str;
}
```

Any suggestions here? Thank you.

Comment: Can you extend your code so we can see the Web method signature? JSON is just a string coming off this service and I believe you should be able to return JSON as a string.

Comment: Thanks Brainwipe. I have added some more code to the question. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is being wrapped in another JSON string.

One way to return a raw JSON string is to change the output type of GetResults() to Stream instead of string.

```
    public System.IO.Stream GetResults()
    {
       string str=//Call RestServiceB which returns response as below.
       "query":"myquery", "results": [ {"name":"result1", "type":"suggest"}, {"name":"result2", "type":"type2"}]"         
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
        "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
    }

    [OperationContract ]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "getresults")]
    String GetResults();
```